# Is it safe to consume packed tea leaves after their expiry?

Tags: food-safety, tea

Is it safe to consume packed tea leaves after their expiry?
After all they might have lost their flavor, but can they be harmful in any way?

Comment: I agree with Jefromi reply but had been sick a single time with an expired tea probably because it was a flavored one (say, with added pineapple and cinnamon). It was just a stomachache but take a look if yours is simply tea or has flavors added.

Comment: @m.bagattini But how did you know that the ache was due to the tea only? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, generally, especially if you've kept them in good conditions. (If the package has been open and it's damp and they might've grown a little mold, that's obviously bad.) The expiration date is for purposes of quality, as you've noted; it doesn't indicate anything about safety. So give them a quick inspection, see if there's enough flavor left for them to be worth using, and go for it.